# Canon scanner lide 600f linux driver

Tags: linux, scanner

Are there any drivers for the Canon LiDE 600F in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)](http://www.sane-project.org/) project provides the scanner drivers on linux. According to the supported devices list, Canon Lide 600f is [not supported](http://www.sane-project.org/unsupported/canon-lide-600.html).

[This blog post](http://www.juergen-ernst.de/info_sane.html) might be of interest. From the post:

> The CanoScan LiDE 600F is a very good scanner. But it has the disadvantage that Canon is unwilling to release the necessary documentation to enable a Linux driver and SANE backend to be written.
>
> So I decided to write a SANE backend for linux on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The CanoScan LiDE 600F is supported by SANE as of version 1.0.31 of `sane-backends`, which adds backend `canon_lide70`.

For more information, see the [author's site](http://www.juergen-ernst.de/info_sane.html):

> 2020-08-23: sane-backends-1.0.31 has been released.
>
> **Backends**
>
> - adds the "canon_lide70" backend